# Defining second derivative boundary condition using DEigensystem

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, boundary-conditions

I tried to solve a fourth-order eigenvalue problem with boundary conditions on high order derivative. 
For example, the following equation,

$$\frac{\partial d}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^4 d}{\partial x^4}=0$$

with a homogeneous Dirichlet condition at the edges and a homogeneous second derivative condition, also at the edges of the domain.

The problem, I think, is with the second derivative condition. All the example I found was for Dirichlet and/or Neumann condition, and then it works.

I tried to define the problem like that,

```
 eqn = D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0;
 bc1 = {u[t, 0] == 0, u[t, 1] == 0};
 bc2 = {Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 1] == 0};
 {vals1, fans1} = 
 DEigensystem[{eqn + bc2, bc1}, u[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, 1];`
```

Or like that,

```
 {vals, fans} = 
 DEigensystem[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0, 
 DirichletCondition[u[x] == 0, 
 True], (D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] /. x -> 0) == 
 0, (D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] /. x -> 1) == 0}, u[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, 4];`
```

both ways I get the following error,

```
Lists {vals,fans} and DEigensystem[{(u^(0,4))[t,x]+(u^(1,0)) 
[t,x]==0,DirichletCondition[u[x]==0,True],(u^(0,2))[t,0]==0,(u^(0,2)) 
[t,1]==0},u[t,x],{x,0,1},4] are not the same shape.
```

Thanks,
Israel.

Comment: Remove the final `;` and, for clarity, also remove `{vals, fans} = `.  Then you will see that `DEigensystem` returns unevaluated.  Because the unevaluated function does not have the same dimension as the list of two elements, `{vals, fans}`, `Set` objects.  So, why does `DEigensystem` (or `NDEigensystem`, for that matter) return unevaluated?  Perhaps,  `DEigensystem` cannot handle fourth-order equations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the debugging suggestion, but now how can I possibly know if the DEigensystem can or cannot handle fourth-order equations?

Comment: Your code is missing the independent variable `t`.  Instead, use `DEigensystem[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + D[u[t, x], {x, 4}] == 0, 
  DirichletCondition[u[t, x] == 0, True], 
  Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 0] == 0, Derivative[0, 2][u][t, 1] == 0}, 
 u[t, x], t, {x, 0, 1}, 4]`.  Nonetheless, this returns unevaluated too.  I can find no `DEigensystem` documentation on fourth-order PDEs or examples on StackExchange, so I do not know whether `DEigensystem` can solve this PDE.  My guess is, No.

Comment: From [Introduction to Differential Equation Solving with DSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroduction.html): "Partial Differential Equations (PDEs), in which there are two or more independent variables and one dependent variable. Finding exact symbolic solutions of PDEs is a difficult problem, but DSolve can solve most first-order PDEs and a limited number of the second-order PDEs found in standard reference books."  If `DSolve` cannot solve a PDE, neither can `DEigensystem`.  However, the PDE clearly can be solved using Fourier series.

Comment: Yes, I solve it by my self but trying to investigate a bit different conditions and to check my solution.
I just started to work with Mathematica, so I don't know the limitation yet. Anyone have a suggestion on how to make sure if the software suppose to solve this equation and I made a mistake, or it does not?